# Javascript Image Transform? [scale and rotate]

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, rotation, scale

I'm looking to build an image transform tool with Javascript.  Something that utilizes handles around the image similar to Photoshop and allows the user to scale and rotate.  I'm looking to make this work in IE 6 and up and Firefox 3+ and Safari 3+.

Does anyone know of a library or tool that could help with this?  I've seen a lot of tools that utilize the Canvas element but that leaves out IT.  I've also seen the Raphael library which might work.  Any other options out there?

Comment: These days it might be ok to use CSS scale and rotate

Answer (score 0):

Check out Raphael library on Github: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this rotorzoom.
It rotates it zooms it's fast and i can do with a few more hits.

http://codepen.io/hex2bin/pen/tHwhF

```js
var requestId = 0;
var animationStartTime = 0;
var img = new Image();
initimg(img);

dst = document.getElementById("dst").getContext("2d");
dst.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
// read the width and height of the canvas
i = 0;

var imageDataDst = dst.getImageData(0, 0, 1024, 512);
var bufDst = new ArrayBuffer(imageDataDst.data.length);
var buf8Dst = new Uint8ClampedArray(bufDst);
var data32Dst = new Uint32Array(bufDst);
var data32Src = new Uint32Array(256*256); 

var scan1=0;
var scan4=0
  
// fill the source array with the image
for (var y = 0; y < 256; ++y) {
  scan4=y*1024*4;  
  for (var x = 0; x < 256; ++x) {        
        data32Src[scan1++] =
        (255   << 24) +    // alpha
        (imageDataDst.data[scan4+2] << 16) +    // blue
        (imageDataDst.data[scan4+1] <<  8) +    // green
        imageDataDst.data[scan4];               // red    
  scan4=scan4+4;
    }  
}

 animationStartTime = window.performance.now();
 requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 var j=0;    


function animate(time) { 
 var height=512;
 var width=1024; 
 j=j+1; 
    var  timestamp = j / 100;       
    var pos;    
    var startY = 128;
    var startX = 128; 
   var i=0;    
    var scaledHeight = 512 + Math.sin(timestamp*1.4) * 500;
    var scaledWidth = 512 + Math.sin(timestamp*1.4) * 500
    var angleRadians = timestamp;
    var deltaX1 = Math.cos(angleRadians) * scaledHeight / 256;
    var deltaY1 = Math.sin(angleRadians) * scaledHeight / 256;
   var deltaY1x256=deltaY1*256;
    var deltaX2 =Math.sin(angleRadians ) * scaledWidth / 256;
    var deltaY2 =-  Math.cos(angleRadians ) * scaledWidth / 256;   
    var h = height;
    while (h--) {
      var x =262144+ startX+deltaX1*-512+deltaX2*-256;
      var y =262144+ startY+deltaY1*-512+deltaY2*-256;
   var y256=y*256;
      var w = width;
      while (w--) {
        //Optimised inner loop. Can it be done better?
        pos =(y256>>0&0xff00)+(x>>0&0xff);
        data32Dst[i++] =data32Src[pos];                    
        x += deltaX1;
        y256 += deltaY1x256;        
        //end of inner loop
      }
      startX += deltaX2
      startY += deltaY2;
    }
    
    imageDataDst.data.set(buf8Dst);
    dst.putImageData(imageDataDst, 0, 0);
 
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function initimg(image1)
{
image1.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="dst" width="1024", height="512">
    Random Canvas
  </canvas>
</body>
```